# 2 SQL queries. Both work independently. When i do them together, result variables from 1st query are empty. Why?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have successfully passed two variables from Javascript to PHP using:

```
$("#element").load("script.php",{dataOne:x,dataTwo:y},function() {alert(y);});
```

Both of the below work, independently:

first for dataOne:

```
$date = strval(gmdate("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['dataOne']))."T00:00:00");
$query = $dbc->prepare("SELECT NEW_DATE, BC_1MONTH, BC_3MONTH, BC_6MONTH, BC_1YEAR, BC_2YEAR, BC_3YEAR, BC_5YEAR, BC_7YEAR, BC_10YEAR, BC_20YEAR, BC_30YEAR  FROM curve WHERE NEW_DATE=?");
$query->bind_param('s',$date);
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,$g,$h,$i,$j,$k,$l);
```

then for dataTwo:

```
$date = strval(gmdate("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['dataTwo']))."T00:00:00");
$query = $dbc->prepare("SELECT NEW_DATE, BC_1MONTH, BC_3MONTH, BC_6MONTH, BC_1YEAR, BC_2YEAR, BC_3YEAR, BC_5YEAR, BC_7YEAR, BC_10YEAR, BC_20YEAR, BC_30YEAR  FROM curve WHERE NEW_DATE=?");
$query->bind_param('s',$date);
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,$g,$h,$i,$j,$k,$l);
```

When I try and combine the two, with this:

```
$fromDate = strval(gmdate("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['dataOne']))."T00:00:00");
$query = $dbc->prepare("SELECT NEW_DATE, BC_1MONTH, BC_3MONTH, BC_6MONTH, BC_1YEAR, BC_2YEAR, BC_3YEAR, BC_5YEAR, BC_7YEAR, BC_10YEAR, BC_20YEAR, BC_30YEAR  FROM curve WHERE NEW_DATE=?");
$query->bind_param('s',$fromDate);
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,$g,$h,$i,$j,$k,$l);

$toDate = strval(gmdate("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['dataTwo']))."T00:00:00");
$query->bind_param('s',$toDate);
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($m,$n,$o,$p,$q,$r,$s,$t,$u,$v,$w,$x);
```

The first query has empty variables. What is the best way for me to store results from my first execution? Ultimately, they are going into a javascript array for use in a  graph.

When I had it working for dataOne in isolation, I was concatenating the results into my javascript like this:

```
 data: ['.$b.','.$c.','.$d.','.$e.','.$f.','.$g.','.$h.','.$i.','.$j.','.$k.','.$l.']
```

I tried doing it in my PHP before executing the second query in order to avoid it being lost. This is currently not working:

```
$curve = '['.$b.','.$c.','.$d.','.$e.','.$f.','.$g.','.$h.','.$i.','.$j.','.$k.','.$l.']';

data: '.$curve.'
```

Comment: What is the value of `y` in the request?

Comment: both and x and y come from the jquery date picker. 11/26/2015. Same format exactly.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what happens? Is there a log of an error on the server? Can you see the request fail?

Comment: may have made a rather silly mistake.. just reviewing and will edit the Q

Comment: I tried it and it works. Try using `$("#element").load("script.php",{'dataOne':x,'dataTwo':y},function() { });`. In your script.php `var_dump($_POST)` and check output from your broswer console. Both x and y are strings, right?

Comment: Im getting x and y into PHP ok. Im querying my database using each of them. The problem is, I can't seem to store variables from both of those DB queries. The second query seems to be overwriting the first.

Answer (score 0):

You don't make a post using `.load()` use `.post()` instead or pass you vars using `$_GET` like

```
    $("#element").load("script.php?dataX="+x+"&dataTwo="+y+" #element");

jquery post  : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
jquery load  : http://api.jquery.com/load/

**EDIT** if you want to use `.load()`

    $( "#element" ).load( "script.php", { "dataOne": x, "dataTwo":y } );

    $date = strval(gmdate("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['dataOne']))."T00:00:00");
    $date2 = strval(gmdate("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['dataTwo']))."T00:00:00"); //<--- same date
    $query = $dbc->prepare("SELECT NEW_DATE, BC_1MONTH, BC_3MONTH, BC_6MONTH, BC_1YEAR, BC_2YEAR, BC_3YEAR, BC_5YEAR, BC_7YEAR, BC_10YEAR, BC_20YEAR, BC_30YEAR  FROM curve WHERE NEW_DATE=?");
    $query->bind_param('s',$date);
    $query->bind_param('s',$date2); //<--- new query
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,$g,$h,$i,$j,$k,$l);
```

Comment: Check `load()` DOC regarding pasting data object: `The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.`

Comment: But OP's code it just fine, using: `{dataOne:x,dataTwo:y}`

Comment: @A. Wolff  Check load() DOC regarding pasting data object:

Comment: You said in answer: `You don't make a post using .load()` But he is and anyway said it works for `$_POST['dataOne']`. Issue is somewhere else